# Mongoose pre save is using incorrect "this" context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

Can anyone figure out what's wrong with my code below?

From documentation it looks like the `this` in Mongoose `.pre('save')` method should be the model itself, but in my code below `this` ends up being an empty object.

```
const Mongoose = require('./lib/database').Mongoose;
const Bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});

userSchema.pre('save', (next) => {

    const user = this;

    Bcrypt.genSalt((err, salt) => {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        Bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, encrypted) => {

            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            user.password = encrypted;
            next();
        });
    });
});

const User = Mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When saving a user, I get the following error `[Error: data and salt arguments required]`.

```
function createUser(email, password, next) {

    const user = new User({
        email: email,
        password: password
    });

    user.save((err) => {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        return next(null, user);
    });
}

createUser('test@email.com', 'testpassword', (err, user) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(user);
    }

    process.exit();
});
```

If I remove the `.pre('save')` then it saves fine of course. Version of Mongoose I'm using is 4.2.6.

Comment: First of all, why do you use `const`? Use `var` instead, then `this` in pre script referers to the record not to the model.

Comment: I'm using `const` because those variables are never changing. I tried changing to `var` and the code runs the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem here is a [fat arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You must rewrite your callback with simple functions. Here small example to show the diff

```
var obj = {};

obj.func1 = function () {
    console.log(this === obj);
};

obj.func2 = () => {
    console.log(this === obj);
};

obj.func1(); // true
obj.func1.bind(obj)(); // true

obj.func2(); // false
obj.func2.bind(obj)(); // false
```

Comment: Thanks. I had just figured this out and was writing up my own answer as you posted this.

Comment: They are just "arrow functions", not "fat arrow functions".

Comment: An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) (с) MDN

Comment: Thank you! A thousand times thank you! Couldn't figure out what was happening as it seemed I followed every instructions to the letter...
Being pretty much a js noob, the differences between arrow functions and simple ones hadn't stuck in my head yet.

This one will, for sure! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to figure out the issue. It turns out Arrow Functions in ES6 preserve the context of the declaring scope rather than using the context of the calling scope so changing the code to the below fixed the issue.

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {

    Bcrypt.genSalt((err, salt) => {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        Bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, encrypted) => {

            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            this.password = encrypted;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you Michelem for giving me the idea that ES6 may have been the culprit.

Comment: Also with the Arrow Functions capturing `this` from the declaring scope, there is no longer any need to declare the `user` variable.

Comment: arrow function was causing my issue, thanks for pointing out context/scope tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
userSchema.pre('save', (next) => {

    var user = this;

    // Try this
    // console.log(user);

    Bcrypt.genSalt(function (err, salt) {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        Bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, encrypted) {

            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            user.password = encrypted;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

But please check user is the right object.

Comment: Still not working. Other than changing `const` to `var` and changing syntax back to ES5, how is this code different from mine?